# Maven + Sonar + Findbugs: Findbugs needs sources to be compiled

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, findbugs

After having worked on one of my project for the first time in months, I wanted to run Sonar to check whether I introduced any new violations. As I have done lots of times before, I've first downloaded the latest stable version of Sonar (sonarqube-4.5.2) And subsequently ran the project with `mvn sonar:sonar`

Everything worked with the Sonar way profile such that I decided to switch to the Findbugs profile. However while analysing the project, I received the following warning:

> [WARN] [13:21:45.287] Findbugs needs sources to be compiled. Please build project before executing sonar or check the location of compiled classes to make it possible for Findbugs to analyse your project.

I had never encountered this problem before *(on the same project, but with older versions of sonar)*, so I searched on the Internet and found that I might need to define `sonar.binaries` to point Sonar to the compiled classes. *(It looks like in my case, Sonar figured this out automatically in the past)*. Nevertheless I added to my `pom.xml` the following properties:

```
  <sonar.sources>${basedir}/src/org/myproject</sonar.sources>
  <sonar.binaries>${basedir}/target/classes/org/myproject</sonar.binaries>
  <sonar.java.binaries>${basedir}/target/classes/org/myproject</sonar.java.binaries>
  <sonar.tests>${basedir}/test/org/myproject</sonar.tests>
```

However, I still get the same error while seeing that the `sonar.binaries` now explicitly points to Maven's target folder.

```
[INFO] [15:18:46.496] Source paths: src/org/myproject
[INFO] [15:18:46.496] Test paths: test/org/myproject
[INFO] [15:18:46.496] Binary dirs: target/classes/org/myproject
```

What I have tried to far:

- Downloaded sonarqube-5.0 which doesn't work at all
- Modified my `pom.xml` to incorporate the following sonar properties

  - sonar.sources --> points to src/org/myproject
  - sonar.binaries --> points to target/classes/org/myproject
  - sonar.java.binaries --> points to target/classes/org/myproject
  - sonar.tests --> points to test/org/myproject
- Tried the same properties, but with absolute paths. I also tried to only specify the path to the parent folders (src, test, target). No success
- I've added a `sonar-project.properties` file with various properties to the project, without any success
- Compiling the project using various Maven lifecycles before running `mvn sonar:sonar`

I'm really perplexed since this worked like a charm in the past.

Answer (score 0):

When running a SonarQube analysis with Maven, you don't need to specify the following properties:

- `sonar.sources`
- `sonar.tests`
- `sonar.libraries`
- `sonar.binaries`

, because the SonarQube Maven does that for you.

Obviously you can try to override them, but what you did is wrong because Maven compiles into "target/classes", so "sonar.binaries" should be set to this folder (not "target/classes/org/myproject").

So to make it simple (and also simpler in fact), just remove those properties from your POM and it will work.

Comment: Hello Fabrice and thanks for your reply. As mentioned in my question, I've only added these properties to see whether this improves the situation or not.
However, when I remove the properties, the findbugs plugin doesn't seem to be able to find any Java related classes (e.g. Couldn't get class info for java/util/Arrays) while the "binary dir" points to target/classes `[INFO] [21:26:08.553] Binary dirs: target/classes`
Since I have never had this problem before, I'm wondering whether my setup could have changed in any way that causes these problems? But it doesn't look like it.

Comment: I think I found the cause of the issue. Namely JDK 8 which was installed in parallel to JDK 7 on my main machine. After I realized that Maven was using the newer JDK I switched towards 1.7 and Findbugs was finally able to see the compiled classes which were apparently not there before... This might just be a misleading error message after all? I have to admit that I also was under the assumption that the recent Sonarqube releases were supporting version 1.8 ? However after some research, I wasn't able to confirm, nor reject this assumption. But it looks like Findbugs 3.0.0 supports Java 1.8.

Comment: With SonarQube 6.1 this is not true anymore. If I remove e.g `sonar.sources` I'll get the following exception `You must define the following mandatory properties for 'your-project': sonar.sources`

Comment: @ChristianLutz Impossible. See the following live example that is analyzed on SonarQube.com: https://github.com/SonarSource/sq-com_example_java-maven-travis => it has no specific property. You're missing something.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam Maybe the reason is I do have an maven multi-module project and I had to create the sonar-project.properties file?

Comment: @ChristianLutz With Maven, you don't need such a file. Have you read the documentation? http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-maven.html

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam Thx, I need to check if all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is another setting for java libraries, not mentioned above:

- sonar.java.libraries

e.g.

```
sonar.java.libraries=lib/*.jar
```